# maven hangs for ~20 mins during the project build (used to work fine)

Tags: java, maven

Building this maven project used to work just fine for quite a while (6 month), but today while executing `mvn clean install` the build start hanging every single time (tried with different versions of mvn including the latest 3.5.0 and against both openJDK & Oracle JDK - result is the same)

`kill -3 PID` output

```
"resolver-5" #491 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6da8bd3800 nid=0x16b3 waiting on condition [0x00007f6d68df3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c658c4a8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"resolver-4" #490 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6da8bd2800 nid=0x16b2 waiting on condition [0x00007f6d69945000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c658c4a8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"resolver-3" #489 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6da8bd9000 nid=0x16b1 waiting on condition [0x00007f6de97bc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c658c4a8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"resolver-2" #488 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6da8bd8800 nid=0x16b0 waiting on condition [0x00007f6de940e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c658c4a8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"resolver-1" #487 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6da8bd7800 nid=0x16af waiting on condition [0x00007f6de930d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c658c4a8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Thread-14" #34 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6d9c0e7800 nid=0x73cd in Object.wait() [0x00007f6de99f7000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.StreamPumper.waitForInput(StreamPumper.java:245)
    - locked <0x00000006cbe26170> (a org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.StreamPumper)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.StreamPumper.run(StreamPumper.java:125)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Thread-13" #33 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6d9c10a800 nid=0x73cb in Object.wait() [0x00007f6de9af8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.StreamPumper.waitForInput(StreamPumper.java:245)
    - locked <0x00000006cbe4a7d8> (a org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.StreamPumper)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.StreamPumper.run(StreamPumper.java:125)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"BuilderThread 3" #19 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6e00927800 nid=0x7373 waiting on condition [0x00007f6dea27d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c6284f48> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"BuilderThread 2" #18 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6e00926800 nid=0x7372 in Object.wait() [0x00007f6dea49b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000006cb6c4780> (a java.lang.UNIXProcess)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.waitFor(UNIXProcess.java:395)
    - locked <0x00000006cb6c4780> (a java.lang.UNIXProcess)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.waitFor(Execute.java:534)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:463)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:628)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:669)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:495)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:313)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:196)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"BuilderThread 1" #17 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6e00926000 nid=0x7371 waiting on condition [0x00007f6dea39b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c6284f48> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"process reaper" #12 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6db02a8800 nid=0x7369 runnable [0x00007f6dea4d5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.lambda$initStreams$3(UNIXProcess.java:289)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess$$Lambda$7/747506922.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"BuilderThread 0" #10 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6e008d4800 nid=0x7367 waiting on condition [0x00007f6dea803000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c6284f48> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Service Thread" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6e000c2800 nid=0x7355 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread2" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6e000b3000 nid=0x7354 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6e000b1800 nid=0x7353 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6e000ae800 nid=0x7352 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6e000ac800 nid=0x7351 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6e00084000 nid=0x7350 in Object.wait() [0x00007f6df05f4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    - locked <0x00000006c231e5c8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6e0007f800 nid=0x734f in Object.wait() [0x00007f6df06f5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
    - locked <0x00000006c2dd4ae0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)

"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6e0000a800 nid=0x7349 waiting on condition [0x00007f6e0a5e2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c6280d98> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService.take(ExecutorCompletionService.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder.multiThreadedProjectTaskSegmentBuild(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:140)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder.build(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

"VM Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6e00077800 nid=0x734e runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6e0001f800 nid=0x734a runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6e00021000 nid=0x734b runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6e00023000 nid=0x734c runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6e00024800 nid=0x734d runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6e000c5000 nid=0x7356 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 280

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 1161728K, used 704160K [0x000000076ab00000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 979968K, 53% used [0x000000076ab00000,0x000000078a929980,0x00000007a6800000)
  from space 181760K, 99% used [0x00000007b4e80000,0x00000007bfffe8f0,0x00000007c0000000)
  to   space 208896K, 0% used [0x00000007a6800000,0x00000007a6800000,0x00000007b3400000)
 ParOldGen       total 1211904K, used 320544K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x0000000709f80000, 0x000000076ab00000)
  object space 1211904K, 26% used [0x00000006c0000000,0x00000006d3908220,0x0000000709f80000)
 Metaspace       used 92817K, capacity 96210K, committed 96512K, reserved 1134592K
  class space    used 10910K, capacity 11975K, committed 12032K, reserved 1048576K
```

Is it some weird deadlock issue ?
Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
Actually the build does not hang forever (**only** 20 - 25 mins). Still it is not clear what is the reason

Comment: were there any changes made to the project? what was the version of java and the version of maven that had it working? Have you tried cleaning the project?

Comment: @JordanGC well, there were changes but nothing special that could break the build in such a way (other teammates does not seem to have this problem). 3.3.9 mvn with 1.8.0_91 java seemed to work just fine (Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: It looks like "BuilderThread 2" is waiting for some other process to finish. The problem may not be with maven at all.

Comment: @IlyaBuziuk restart the computer, I'm assuming you're using GitHub or some other source management system. Load the version you knew worked and try that. If it works, then your changes introduced a bug somewhere. if it doesn't work, then it's your environment. Looks to me like something is hijacking resources. Doesn't look like a maven issue as far as i can tell. The reason i said restart your computer is because as Rob said, thread 2 is waiting for another process to finish.

Comment: @JordanGS restart does not help :-) this looks like environment issue but it is just supper weird to get it out of the blue (I have not change env in any way as far as I can tell)

Comment: @IlyaBuziuk the first thing i would do is check if the version from 6 months ago works, if it doesn't then it's the environment. In which case i would get a second PC or VM and install what i need which is Java and Maven, then try to compile the project. If it works on the machine which just got configured and doesn't have anything running in the background. Then there's something which changed in your current machine. At that point i would just backup files and nuke the machine personally. Since it takes 30-60minutes to do a backup and reinstall the OS whereas troubleshooting could take hours

Comment: @JordanGS sounds relevant but I just do not want to reinstall OS every time I hit some build issue ;-)

Comment: @IlyaBuziuk first figure out if it's the environment, if it is. Then try to narrow down if it's a thread issue and go from there. We need to narrow down what it could be because as of right now, there's too many possibilities.

If you use jvisualvm.exe then you can watch the threads for the application and look at a heap dump.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maven 3.5.x has some pretty terrible bugs, namely:

- [Metadata download hangs for repository with cache lifetime](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6307)
- [Maven dependency resolution locks up](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5592)

What is specifically happening is that if you are building a project with submodules or multiple projects, Maven 3.5.x sporadically locks up when downloading duplicate dependencies. **Example:** Let spring-expression-4.3.5.RELEASE be a dependency of two or more project POMs. It's downloaded into the Maven Repo by project 1 at ".m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.3.5.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar" (of course, with the POM and checksum files). When project 2 goes to check/download the same dependency in the same location, it locks up for 20 minutes and then reports "0 B" was downloaded in the logs.

Until the Maven team addresses this issue in the 3.5.x releases, we pulled back to **Maven 3.3.9** and the problem vanished. (NOTE: This was regularly reproducible at the same point in dependency resolution in our project.)

Comment: Note that as of Maven 3.5.3, [the deadlock in dependency resolution has been fixed](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.5.3/release-notes.html).

Answer (score 3):

I have been having the maven problem with hanging artifactory download on my Ubuntu (21.10) with all of the following versions:

- 3.3.9
- 3.6.3
- 3.8.4

Maven hangs while downloading a dependency from artifactory server.
If you actually go to the .m2/repository/... you will see there is a .lock file and the artifact is a part files with 0 size. Maven seems to induce a deadlock to itself.

I tried using 1 thread:

```
mvn -T 1 clean verify
```

did not help much. I also tried adding this to my ~/.mavenrc:

```
-Dmaven.artifact.threads=1
```

also did not help.

What seems to solve the issue is deleting the lock files on the hanging dependency.Either by going to the dependency directory or within the m2 repository like this:

```
cd ~/
rm -rf .m2/repository/**.lock
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try https://github.com/jcgay/maven-profiler to profile the build process. Perhaps it's an issue in specific plugin e.g. surefire taking 20 mins because someone committed a test with  `Thread.sleep(1200000);`.

Comment: It's not. They upgraded the resolver and it hangs in dependency resolution and downloading. (Note the 'resolver' threads hanging in wait states from the posted core dump.) I'm not disputing this could help find out the exact root problem, but I had no desire to deep dive into Maven code for a bug report.