# Build Failure using jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am running my selenium scripts using jenkins 2.1 .

When I run through jenkins, the build fails.

Below are the versions used, I tried changing many version but it didn't work out:

maven compiler -2.4
maven surefire -2.7.1
selenium 2.44:

```
   [ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure

E:\Jino_testing\Automation_project\Guru99\src\test\java\PageObject\Locators.java:[17,38] error: package com.relevantcodes.extentreports does not exist
E:\Jino_testing\Automation_project\Guru99\src\test\java\PageObject\Locators.java:[19,38] error: package com.relevantcodes.extentreports does not exist
E:\Jino_testing\Automation_project\Guru99\src\test\java\PageObject\Locators.java:[156,2] error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ExtentReports
  location: class Locators
E:\Jino_testing\Automation_project\Guru99\src\test\java\PageObject\Locators.java:[156,25] error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable ExtentReports
  location: class Locators
E:\Jino_testing\Automation_project\Guru99\src\test\java\PageObject\Locators.java:[162,13] error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable LogStatus
  location: class Locators
E:\Jino_testing\Automation_project\Guru99\src\test\java\PageObject\Locators.java:[174,14] error: cannot find symbol

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Apr 04 11:15:51 IST 2018
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/57M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving E:\Jino_testing\Automation_project\Guru99\pom.xml to Guru99/Guru99/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/Guru99-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Maven is not configured properly on your Jenkins instance. Go to global tools configuration and recheck.

Comment: @Manmohan_singh  i configured like this                                         name-MAVEN HOME                                                                                          MAVEN_HOME-E:\Jino_testing\Test Automation\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.2

Comment: Then , you should check the path up to pom.xml .

Comment: @Manmohan_singh  I checked C:\Users\Jino\.jenkins\jobs\Guru\workspace but its empty

Comment: So that's the cause of ERROR: Failed to parse POMs. If you are specifying the project path manually, then it is up to you.

Comment: @Manmohan_singh  i specified the path manually, is this due to any version isssue?

Comment: Read my answer below.

Comment: @Manmohan_singh   copied the pom file to this location but didn't worked

Comment: please give the screenshot on your setting of `Source Code Management` and `Build` section in your Jenkins job.

Comment: improved readability.

Comment: I don't think that this question is related to Selenium. Please remove that tag and references. Thanks.

Comment: "Maven 3.5.x has some pretty terrible bugs. ..."  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49059946/325452

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt that your pom.xml is located at `C:\Users\Jino\.jenkins\jobs\Guru\workspace`

*Workspace has multiple projects*. You should **relook the project path** where the target pom.xml can be found. Something like.

```
C:\Users\Jino\.jenkins\jobs\Guru\workspace\<projectName>\pom.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing maven version 3.3.9

Also can you confirm if the code that you are using in jenkins to build works fine(Building) in an IDE, if so use the exact same maven version which is used there.

`Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to Channel to Maven [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151/bin/java, -cp, C:\Users\Jino\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven33-agent-1.8.1.jar;E:\Jino_testing\Test Automation\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.2\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;E:\Jino_testing\Test Automation\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.2/conf/logging, jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main, E:\Jino_testing\Test Automation\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.2, C:\Users\Jino\.jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-3.19.jar, C:\Users\Jino\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven33-interceptor-1.8.1.jar, C:\Users\Jino\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.8.1.jar, 58713]`

Observed the above error from your code and it mentions maven 3.5 when you mentioned maven-compiler -2.4.

Comment: its working now, but the browser is not loading, my test is running , showing all messages but the browser is not loading.wat  can be the reason?

Comment: What do you mean by browser is not loading ?? are you getting a 404 error ? has the war file been deployed to tomcat ?? if it has been deployed to tomcat have you started tomcat ?? you need to give more details . I can only guess based on a one liner you have mentioned :P

Comment: i means on building throgh jenkins, the browser doesn't loads( browser not opening) but my test is running.i am using jenkins.exe ,

Comment: Why are you using jenkins.exe ?? why not run it on your browser(localhost:8080) default port which has UI and makes life a lot easier.. also can you check the logs and see where the issue is occuring

Comment: jenkins.exe is similar to war, we can run in localhost:8080 and check logs but i dont understand why the browser is not openinf

Comment: jenkins.exe is similar to war, we can run browser in localhost:8080 and check logs, but i dont understand why the browser is not opening

Comment: Jenkins is basically a tomcat instance, so you need to check the logs(it will be there in the location you installed jenkins)where you ran jenkins.exe you need to read the logs and find out what the issue it ... cant help you further

Comment: initially i used jenkins.war but showing "jenkins stopped", can u help me to set jenkins  war

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168202/discussion-between-rohit-thomas-and-jino).